How i can get Hyva for development and learning purpose without buying subscription
How i can get Hyva for learning purpose without buying subscription as a Magento developer just for exploring. I know they have subscription fee but is their any way i can get it for learning purpose.

I think the only you have to buy the subscription to get the Hyva

You must purchase the license in order to do that.
